# Trying to access list option in Jquery via C# web browser

Tags: c#, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to select an option from a list using a c# web browser, here is the code from the web page I am accessing, I am not sure how to select the option I would like.

```
<input type="search" 
id="fl-input-3053" 
name="" 
autocomplete="off" 
ng-required="$mdAutocompleteCtrl.isRequired" 
ng-readonly="$mdAutocompleteCtrl.isReadonly" 
ng-disabled="$mdAutocompleteCtrl.isDisabled" 
ng-model="$mdAutocompleteCtrl.scope.searchText" 
ng-keydown="$mdAutocompleteCtrl.keydown($event)" 
ng-blur="$mdAutocompleteCtrl.blur()" 
ng-focus="$mdAutocompleteCtrl.focus()" 
aria-owns="ul-3053" 
aria-label="User to Assign Dashboard" 
aria-autocomplete="list" 
aria-haspopup="true" 
aria-activedescendant="" 
aria-expanded="false" 
class="ng-pristine 
md-input 
ng-empty 
ng-valid-minlength 
ng-valid-maxlength 
ng-valid 
ng-valid-required 
ng-touched" 
aria-invalid="false" 
style="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a AutoComplete textbox with angularjs.
Take a look at this [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/sebmade/swfjT/) or have a look at this [`ngAutocomplete`](https://github.com/wpalahnuk/ngAutocomplete) directive